# Efficient way to implement lazy deletion in open hash using java

Tags: java, string, hashtable, implementation, quadratic-probing

I'm implementing an open hash table using quadratic probe. My data base is java String[] (my objects are limited **only to strings**). For deletion I use lazy deletion, but I want to implement it really efficient. I'm sure there is more elegant solution than holding a brand new array of flags (active / empty / deleted).

I thought of assigning some known constant string when deleting (for example "", the empty string), and when needed, to compare cell content to the pointer of that string itself (using == instead of String.equals). That way I know the cell is deleted but an active cell can hold **any kind** of string (including an empty one) because it will never **point** to our constant one.

Is there any problem with my idea?

Comment: How would you do it inefficiently?

Comment: I don't think you can lazily delete keys without using some additional storage, e.g., a deleted flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single array of `Object`s, elements can either be `null` (free slot), `String` (full slot) and special

```
private static final Object TOMBSTONE = new Object();
```

for lazily deleted slots.